# How to open a page, check a checkbox and click OK using a bookmark?

Tags: javascript, bookmarks

I'm trying to make a bookmark in my browser with a javascript that:

1. goes to a specific url
2. check two checkboxes on that page
3. clicks the "ok" button on that page

I have got the following:

```
javascript: 
window.location.assign("url"); 
document.getElementById("checkbox 1").checked = true; document.getElementById("checkbox 2").checked = true; document.getElementById("okButton").click();
```

the `location.assign` works without any problems, but once I'm on the page the checkboxes are not checked. When I go to the page manually and run the checkbox lines and the click line, it works as expected.

Anyone got a suggestion on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You may need to wait for the elements to load first.

Comment: May I suggest you to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627983/calling-a-javascript-function-after-loading-a-page-with-window-location-assign first? It may change your way of thinking

Comment: You could use query string parameters and depending on the values or if they are present, you could perform the actions using js onload?