# Javascript - How to wait event listener end to next iteration

Tags: javascript

I am facing problems with an event listener inside a for loop.

I have basically this:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  
  //window url change here, each iteration open a different url
  console.log('what??');

  window.addEventListener('load', aperture, true);

  function aperture() {
    console.log('here');
    window.close();
  }
}
```

So, I have to wait window load in order to execute the function, and then go to next for iteration and do the same. But what I obtain looking this logs is:

```
    what??
    what??
    here
    here
```

How can I wait event listener finish between iterations ?

Comment: You should look at [`Promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and `chaining`.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The document will only load once. If you were to wait, then the second "here" would never fire. This smells like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: What is your end goal? Why are you adding event listeners in a loop? Smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)...

Comment: Re edit: Don't hide important bits of your question in a comment in the middle of the code. Open with a clear problem statement. Your edit means this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627983/calling-a-javascript-function-after-loading-a-page-with-window-location-assign).

Comment: I extract data from html of several dynamic urls and I can´t do it with a xmlhttprequest, so I open window with url, extract data, store it in an array, close and repeat with new generated url.

Comment: @el_apeiron - if you can't do it with ajax you certainly cant do it by opening a new window. the same limitations apply to cross site scripting.

Comment: Ok, but going like this, there should be any way of wait listener ending before next iteration

Answer (score 1):

I'll just answer the question you actually asked...

> How can I wait event listener finish between iterations ?

You can't do it with a real loop, the only way to make an asynchronous "loop" is to use recursion, which can be slightly complicated. The idea is to create a function that will call itself when it's ready to iterate again.

```js
(function myLoop(){
  
  // do something that takes a while
  setTimeout(function(){
     console.log("did something");
     
     // then recurse...
     myLoop();
     
  }, 1500);
  
})();
```

If you're looping over an array, the concept is similar... Here's a [general purpose function](https://gist.github.com/Pamblam/61a636dd02a8dc43fa6c01f667a05a64) I wrote to do do it...

```js
var myArray = ["a","b","c","d"];
var myLoop = slowLoop(myArray, (itm, idx, cb)=>{
    
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log(`doing something with ${itm} which is item number ${idx} in the array`);
        
        // call cb when finished
        cb();
        
    }, 1000);
    
});

// when it's done....
myLoop.then(()=>{

    console.log("All done looping");

});


/**
 * Execute the loopBody function once for each item in the items array, 
 * waiting for the done function (which is passed into the loopBody function)
 * to be called before proceeding to the next item in the array.
 * @param {Array} items - The array of items to iterate through
 * @param {Function} loopBody - A function to execute on each item in the array.
 *  This function is passed 3 arguments - 
 *   1. The item in the current iteration,
 *   2. The index of the item in the array,
 *   3. A function to be called when the iteration may continue.
 * @returns {Promise} - A promise that is resolved when all the items in the 
 *  in the array have been iterated through.
 */
function slowLoop(items, loopBody) {
 return new Promise(f => {
  done = arguments[2] || f;
  idx = arguments[3] || 0;
  let cb = items[idx + 1] ? () => slowLoop(items, loopBody, done, idx + 1) : done;
  loopBody(items[idx], idx, cb);
 });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I had thought in recursivity, but i was trying to find an easier way. Thank you

Comment: @el_apeiron please upvote this answer if you find it useful and/or accept if it does solve your issue